# Result of validation different between Chrome and the AMPProject Validator

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, amp-html

I'm trying to get my AMP pages working, and I have a weird issue: everything seems good to me regarding all the guidelines to have valid AMP pages, when I ask Chrome to validate one of my pages, it works like a charm, but when I go on the AMPProject Validator page, the same page I check fails the validation, and the code that the validator presents me looks like a mix between my regular theme and my AMP theme.

The website runs on Drupal, and I did not have this issue on my dev environment, and the only difference between my dev and production environments is the presence of Cloudflare in front of my production environment. Can the problem come from Cloudflare? Did anyone already have that kind of issue?

Thanks a lot in advance!
Francois

Comment: sharing your code might encourage others to help you

Answer (score 1):

The most likely answer is that your server is responding with different outputs to your browser's HTTP request vs the HTTP request that https://validator.ampproject.org/ uses to fetch the same page. The requests will have different useragents, cookies, ips, etc. Check your server configuration to see what's going on and why it is responding differently.

The text in the preview area on https://validator.ampproject.org/ displays exactly what your server returned to that tool.